# Regarding focusing on the web part on a site on sharepoint after clicking

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have deployed 3 web parts on a site on Sharepoint server. In my 3rd web part, I have a functionality which needs a button click. Now when I click that button, the whole page gets refreshed and I have to scroll down to see the change that has happened due to clicking that functionality in 3rd web part. Is there any way by which when i click on any point of the web part, the page is reloaded but the control point or the focus remains to the same position where I clicked...
Help me out.
Regards,
Jigar

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the answer to my question. I just had to write onscroll=true in my Web.config file.
Thanks community.